# свою функцию с auth/models.py в project/models.py

Tags: django, классы, импорт

Привет, форум,

чтобы дать controller значение True by is_staff и значение False by is_superuser. Я написал дополнительную функцию под названием «create_controller» в django.contrib.auth.models в классе UserManager.
Пока все хорошо, все работает.

но:

- функция «create_controller» должна быть передана project/models.py, чтобы впоследствии быть распознанной системой управления версиями.

PS:

- Функция «create_controller» адресуется в fill_db.py (см. раздел fill_db.py)
- функция «create_controller» возвращает self._create_user.
- Функция «_create_user» должна оставаться в django.contrib.auth.models

Я новичок, и мне нужна ваша поддержка. Готовое решение не требуется. Мне просто нужны советы для решения проблемы.
Я много пробовал с импортом, к сожалению, без успеха.

Кто-нибудь знает, что и как мне нужно импортировать, если я хочу иметь функцию «create_controller» в project/models.py?

И как нужно изменить fill_db.py?

Заранее спасибо

вырезка из django.contrib.auth.models (Класс UserManager)

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

```
use_in_migrations = True

def _create_user(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
   Creates and saves a User with the given username, email and password.
   """
    if not username:
        raise ValueError('The given username must be set')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    username = self.model.normalize_username(username)
    user = self.model(username=username, email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_user(self, username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields):
    ...

def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    ...

def create_controller(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError('Controller must have is_staff=True.')

    return self._create_user(username, email, password, **extra_fields)
```

вырезка из fill_db.py

pruefer1 = User.objects.create_controller(username='pruefer',

```
                                first_name="vorname_pruefer1",
                                last_name="nachname_pruefer1",
                                password='django_test',
                                email="test@web.de")
```

pruefer1.save()

Answer (score 0):

create_controller, в данном случае, это метод класса UserManager. Вы не можете использовать его просто с моделью User.

Для того, чтобы это сделать, Вам нужен кастомный UserManager, который будет наследоваться от базового, и в котором будет ваш метод create_controller. Затем в модели User следует указать, что в качестве objects будет использоваться именно Ваш UserManager.

Допустим, Ваш кастомный менеджер называется как-нибудь вроде CustomUserManager.

Тогда в User следует добавить строку вида

```
objects = CustomUserManager()
```